# scrollTop is not working in Firefox as expected?

Tags: jquery

So my problem is that is code works in Chrome, but in Firefox its always `display:none`,. Any suggestion what is wrong?

```
 $(document).on('scroll', function() {

            if($(this).scrollTop()>=$('.compare-wrapper').position().top){
                $('.compare-menu-fixed').css('display','block');
            }
            else{

                 $('.compare-menu-fixed').css('display','none');

            }
});
```

Comment: put your html code as well. making a fiddle or snippet helps you to achieve the answer faster

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `offset().top` to get the distance from top to till `.compare-wrapper` where your div is placed. Try as below,

> The .position() method allows us to retrieve the current position of
>   an element relative to the offset parent. Contrast this with
>   .offset(), which retrieves the current position relative to the
>   document.

```js
 $(document).on('scroll', function() {

   if($(this).scrollTop()>=$('.compare-wrapper').offset().top){
             $('.compare-menu-fixed').css('display','block');
      }
  else{
       $('.compare-menu-fixed').css('display','none');
       }
});
```

```css
body{
  height:1600px;
}
.compare-wrapper{
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  background:#111;
  margin-top:100px;
  position:relative;
}
.compare-wrapper > .compare-menu-fixed{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:#f22;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="compare-wrapper">
<div class="compare-menu-fixed"></div>
</div>
```